# Avoiding Feature limit exceeded on layer in ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, limitations

My code as below:

require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (Map, SceneView, FeatureLayer) {

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/votes_popup_final3/FeatureServer/0");
var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets",
    ground: "world-elevation",
    layers: [featureLayer]
});
var view = new SceneView({
    container: "viewDiv",     
    map: map,                
    scale: 5000000,         
    center: [-110, 32] 
});
```

});

The result as below:
[image]

Only show a little part of all features. And show the below error in Firebug:

[esri.layers.graphics.controllers.SnapshotController] Feature limit exceeded on layer " Votes popup final3 - All Votes ". Not all features are shown.

But when use MapView, it can show all features. The code as below:

require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/widgets/Legend",
  "esri/widgets/LayerList",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Legend, LayerList) {

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/votes_popup_final3/FeatureServer/0");
var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets",
    layers: [featureLayer]
});

var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv", 
    map: map,
    zoom: 4, 
    center: [-110, 32]
});
```

});

Of course need include webgl as below:

var dojoConfig = {
  has: {
    "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
  }
};

This time it can show all of features. The page shows as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The WebGL is only available, as beta version, for 2D (`MapView`) and not for 3D (`SceneView`)

You can see that in the [ESRI documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#fetching-improvements):

> Starting at version 4.5, you can render FeatureLayers with WebGL in 2D MapViews. [...] By default, FeatureLayer is rendered using Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG), which limits the number of features that can be displayed in the view. WebGL-rendered FeatureLayers overcome that limitation, allowing the user to display hundreds of thousands, potentially millions, of features in the browser.